# Cobol invalid number on linkage-section

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

So, I'm studying Cobol and qhen I try to build my code, I get the following error:

> soma.cob:8: Error: Invalid level number 'linkage-section'

the file soma.cob, is that:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID.    SOMA.

data division.
working-storage section.
77 RESPT PIC 9(2) VALUE ZEROS.

linkage-section.
01 CAMP1 PIC 9(2).
01 CAMP2 PIC 9(2).

PROCEDURE DIVISION USING CAMP1 CAMP2.
    COMPUTE RESPT = CAMP1+CAMP2.        
    DISPLAY RESPT.
```

so, where is the problem ????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `linkage-section.`, you need to write `linkage section.`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does provide an answer. COBOL syntax calls for linkage section. linkage-section is a source code error. And that's exactly where the problem is.  Apologies if the wording of the answer sounded terse.